# How to let activator use local ivy2 repository by default

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, typesafe-activator

I have installed a Scala library on a local repository and here is my filesystem structure:

```
j3d@gonzo:~/.ivy2/local/com.mydomain/testlib_2.11/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT$ ll
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 7 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 docs/
drwxrwxr-x 2 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 ivys/
drwxrwxr-x 2 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 jars/
drwxrwxr-x 2 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 poms/
drwxrwxr-x 2 j3d j3d 4096 Mär 11 17:02 srcs/
```

Here are my resolvers in `Build.scala`:

```
val resolvers = Seq(
  Resolver.url("Local repository", url("file:///home/j3d/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work... I always get the following error:

```
[error] (common/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.mydomain#testlib_2.11;0.1.0: not found
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be a stupid question, but do you add `resolvers` variable to `resolvers` property: `Keys.resolvers ++= resolvers`?

Comment: Yes of course, I did.

Comment: I see you are probably using multimodule setup. Can you show what `common/resolvers` returns?